# Does the name in a parameter type determine if the class is generic?

Tags: java, generics

I just started reading about generic classes. I'm wondering if the name of the parameter type affects what gets passed in. So does code 1 and 2 work exactly the same way? Are they both generic classes? Thanks!

```
// Code 1
public class Bar<AnyType> {
    private AnyType a;
}

// Code 2
public class Bar<Lalaland> {
    private Lalaland a;  
}
```

Comment: Try it. But, no, it doesn't change anything. Your two classes are equivalent. Note that you should typically use a single letter for the generic type variable. Your type variable might obscure other type names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works the exact same way, just as choosing a different variable name works the same way.

```
int anyInt = 5;
```

vs.

```
int lalaland = 5;
```

But always be careful that you choose a generic type parameter name different than an existing class name.  While it's legal, it leads to plenty of confusion when the type parameter is mistaken for the class name.

```
// Don't do this.
public class Bar<Integer>  // confusing!
```

According to [the Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html),

> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types